# My bitcoin transaction hasn’t confirmed for 2 months

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I sent a transaction with a very low transaction fee and the transaction has been waiting to be confirmed for the past 2 months. How long until the bitcoin is returned to my wallet or sent through?

Answer (score 0):

If a transaction has not been confirmed then the coins have not left your address / wallet. Generally you will have an RBF (Replace By Fee) option that will allow you to signal to the Bitcoin full node network that you wish to get this transaction confirmed faster, in which case you can bump your sat per byte fee rate.